# Drupal Path Auto from Taxonomy Term

Tags: url, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, pathauto

So i created a new content type to create product pages and i created a vocabulary with all my different categories in it for my products.

What I want is to be able to select the correct category while creating the product and have the url based on this choice.

My taxonomy vocabulary is laid out with multiple sub categories eg,

Product 
group 1 --- group 1 SubCategory1  ---SubCateory1 product
        --- group 1 SubCategory2
        --- group 1 SubCategory3
group 2
group 3
group 4

That's a bit hard to lay out properly but I want my url to go like

content/maincategory/subcategory/subcategory/title

I added the term to the content type so as I have to pick it once im creating a new product which is simple enough. The resulting Machine name is **taxonomy_product_categories**

I then went to set the content path/ URL aliases for the content type.

I tried **content/[node:taxonomy_product_categories:0:parents:join-path]/[node:title]**

This doesn't work.

Have you any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Entity tokens module and clear the cache.